# URLError: "Connection Refused" in Python

Tags: android, python, android-emulator

I am trying to run a python script on an android emulator. However, I am getting a "connection refused"  (URLError) in Python. My server is running on the same laptop (localhost) and on the same port.The server has been designed to print out the various requests sent to it on the terminal itself. However, I have not been able to make a connection with the web server even once(i.e., it does not print out the web request sent to it by the python script). But I can access my other files on the web server by writing their URLs on the address bar of the web browser itself and the server prints the requests on the terminal accordingly.

The complete python script is as follows:

```
import android
import json
import time

import urllib
import urllib2

hello_msg     = "Welcome to Coach Kelly's Timing App"
list_title    = "Here is your list of athletes:"
quit_msg      = "Quitting Coach Kelly's App."
web_server    = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080'
get_names_cgi = '/cgi-bin/generate_names.py'

def send_to_server(url, post_data=None):

    if post_data:
        page = urllib2.urlopen(url, urllib.urlencode(post_data))

    else:
        page = urllib2.urlopen(url)

    return(page.read().decode("utf8"))


app = android.Android()


def status_update(msg, how_long=2):

    app.makeToast(msg)
    time.sleep(how_long)


status_update(hello_msg)


athlete_names = sorted(json.loads(send_to_server(web_server + get_names_cgi)))

app.dialogCreateAlert(list_title)
app.dialogSetSingleChoiceItems(athlete_names)
app.dialogSetPositiveButtonText('Select')
app.dialogSetNegativeButtonText('Quit')
app.dialogShow()

resp = app.dialogGetResponse().result

status_update(quit_msg)
```

And the following is my traceback output:

```
Traceback(most recent call last):
File "/mnt/sdcard/sl4a/scipts/coachapp_1.py", line 37 in <module>  
    athlete_names = sorted(json.loads(send_to_server(web_server + get_names_cgi)))  
File "/mnt/sdcard/sl4a/scipts/coachapp_1.py", line 20 in send_to_server  
    page = urllib2.urlopen(url)  
File "/home/manuel/AptanaStudio3Workspace/python-for-android/python-build/output/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 124 in urlopen   
File "/home/manuel/AptanaStudio3Workspace/python-for-android/python-build/output/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 383 in open   
File "/home/manuel/AptanaStudio3Workspace/python-for-android/python-build/output/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 401 in _open   
File "/home/manuel/AptanaStudio3Workspace/python-for-android/python-build/output/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 361 in _call_chain  
File "/home/manuel/AptanaStudio3Workspace/python-for-android/python-build/output/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 1130 in http_open   
File "/home/manuel/AptanaStudio3Workspace/python-for-android/python-build/output/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 1105 in do_open   

urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>
```

I referred to the other threads regarding this discussion but was unable to get a very satisfactory answer regarding this. So, any help would be appreciated in clearing out the URLError

Comment: The server it's on the Host machine and the client in the emulator?  Then i guess it's not localhost where you should be looking for. Don't know what VM are you using, but you need some kind of nexus which connects both computer and virtual machine intranets. Correct me if I'm missing something

Comment: I am using Nexus One VM (and Android 2.2). So, where can I put my server process then and what should I look for, if not the localhost?

Comment: assuming you are using android studio http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking

Comment: Thanks very much! The link was really useful. Yes, you were right. The emulator cant access the development machine's loopback interface. Had to use the special address '10.0.2.2' instead of '127.0.0.1'